# SSD adapter to connect to PC via USB

Tags: usb, ssd, adapter

I have this SSD: [PM981 NVMe SAMSUNG 512GB](https://www.esseshop.it/hd-ssd-m2-512gb-samsung-pm981-nvme-pcie-typ-2280-bulk-p-96622.html) that I took from a previous PC I bought, that I don't use anymore. I want to connect it to my new PC via USB to get some files. I bought [this adapter](https://www.amazon.it/Enclosure-Beikell-Tool-Free-Adattatore-M-Key/dp/B0BGS3NZ4C/ref=sr_1_5) to do it: the SSD enters correctly, but the PC doesn't detect it, so I guess I bought the wrong adapter.

Can someone help me to find the right adapter? Or is it not a problem of adapters? (I know that Hardware Recommendations isn't for tech support: if the problem is not the adapter I'm not asking troubleshooting [but in case, is there a stack exchange site to ask tech support on something like this?] so just tell me that the problem isn't the adapter; otherwise, I would be glad if someone could recommend a working adapter).

**UPDATE**

I suspect that the problem is with the formatting, because the ssd is now detected (it makes the windows sound when it recognizes that a usb device has been plugged in), but the ssd doesn’t appear in the devices (in the “files” app).

Comment: Since your SSD uses PCIe to communicate with the computer, your computer should support some kinda PCIe for it to function (like Thunderbolt 3/4)

Comment: @Irsu85 I have a Thunderbolt 3 port, but, by checking on the “windows thunderbolt manager”, it seems like it doesn’t see/detect anything when I connect it.

Comment: That adapter is NVMe to USB, so it should work. I would try to debug why the PC isn't detecting it - does it show in Device Manager? Maybe the drive isn't appearing because it isn't formatted in a way Windows is happy with?

Comment: @user1908704 yes thanks, I suspect that the problem is with the formatting, because the ssd is now detected (it makes the windows sound when it recognizes that a usb device has been plugged in), but the ssd doesn’t appear in the devices (in the “files” app)

Comment: Sound can be that it recognizes the adapter (which is a device of itself). To check if it recognizes the SSD check in Disk Management

Comment: @YisroelTech yes it is detected in disk management, but it says that the disk is not initializable and that there is 0mb capacity / space allocated